# How to set one select box equal to another?

Tags: javascript

I have two identical select boxes (aside from their names, of course), and I need to have the value of the second select box be set equal to the value of the first when a checkbox is checked. Here's part of my code:

```
<form id="theForm" name="theForm">

<select name="stateSelect" id="stateSelect">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
</select>

<select name="stateSelect2" id="stateSelect2">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="checky" onClick="doStuff()">
</form>

doStuff() 
{
    // change it from here
}
```

So, I've tried a bunch of different things, including code I've found on forums and on SO, but nothing seems to work. What code should I have in my javascript function so that when the function runs the second select box is set equal to the first?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have jQuery or an other JS framework enabled? I'd rather ask, because without it it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: @haltabush -- No, I don't have any framework :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var s1=document.getElementById('stateSelect');
var s2=document.getElementById('stateSelect2');
s1.onchange=function(){
    s2.value=s1.value;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rLEvD/

Comment: Stewe - thanks, that looks promising, but I'm afraid I don't quite understand it and I need it to be slightly different than that. Is there any way to make it so that the second select box's value is changed inside any old function, instead of the special one you made?

Comment: Yes, just use `s2.value=s1.value;` in your function.

Comment: Not particularly cross browser and depends on the options having equivalent value attributes. It may be more suitable to use `s2.selectedIndex = s1.selectedIndex` which gives the same result in this case.

Comment: How is that not cross browser? Is it `.value` that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

(Where `#sel1` is the id of your first select, `#sel2` is the id of your second select and `#checkbox` is the id of your checkbox:)

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(){
    if ($('#sel2').attr('disabled') != 'disabled') {
        $('#sel2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#sel2').val($('#sel1').val());}     
    else
        $('#sel2').removeAttr('disabled');
});
    $('#sel1').change(function(){
    if ($('#sel2').attr('disabled') == 'disabled')
        $('#sel2').val($(this).val());
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/u4n7n/

Comment: Oops, didn't see that you weren't using a framework until after I posted. I guess that's what I get for assuming...